# Groovy 2.4 - Binding - getProperty - do not depend on try/catch block

Tags: groovy

Groovy Binding class method getProperty() relies on try/catch block. We observed high CPU utilization under heavy load and the APM tool indicates this method is contributing to the high CPU.

**Question 1**: how to implement the getProperty method that doesn't depend on the try/catch block (exactly like the comment in source code says)?

**Question 2**: in what scenario does "super.getProperty(property);" actually return a value? An example code will be helpful.

Source: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/commit/b58342060031f517d6ba42a64dd3ddf392e820bb#diff-c5805e4bd65201710573d9582ebaf461

**Version in 2.4.12**

```
/**
 * Overloaded to make variables appear as bean properties or via the subscript operator
 */
public Object getProperty(String property) {
    /** @todo we should check if we have the property with the metaClass instead of try/catch  */
    try {
        return super.getProperty(property);
    }
    catch (MissingPropertyException e) {
        return getVariable(property);
    }
}
```

**Proposal: is this code correct?**

```
public Object getProperty(String property) {        
        if(getMetaClass().hasProperty(property)!=null){
            return super.getProperty(property);
        } else {
            return getVariable(property);
        }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**
The proposal doesn't work. getMetaClass().hasProperty(property) seems to be in turn (via nested calls) calling getProperty() and the program fails with StackOverflowError (cyclic calls)

```
objc[50062]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.AbstractConcurrentMap.getOrPut(AbstractConcurrentMap.java:37)
    at com.webmd.cp.rule.service.CustomBinding.getProperty(CustomBinding.groovy:24)
    at com.webmd.cp.rule.service.CustomBinding.getVariable(CustomBinding.groovy:62)
    at com.webmd.cp.rule.service.CustomBinding.getProperty(CustomBinding.groovy:27)
    at com.webmd.cp.rule.service.CustomBinding.getVariable(CustomBinding.groovy:62)
    at com.webmd.cp.rule.service.CustomBinding.getProperty(CustomBinding.groovy:27)
    at com.webmd.cp.rule.service.CustomBinding.getVariable(CustomBinding.groovy:62)
    at com.webmd.cp.rule.service.CustomBinding.getProperty(CustomBinding.groovy:27)
    at com.webmd.cp.rule.service.CustomBinding.getVariable(CustomBinding.groovy:62)
    at com.webmd.cp.rule.service.CustomBinding.getProperty(CustomBinding.groovy:27)
    at com.webmd.cp.rule.service.CustomBinding.getVariable(CustomBinding.groovy:62)
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Hi @lospejos - added specific questions. Thanks!